# How to override hardware back button action in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, button, ionic2, ionic3, back

I want to know which function is called when we click ion-navbar back button by default in ionic 3.
I want to call the same function on hardware back button click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  **[registerBackButtonAction](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction)** of **[Platform Service](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/)**.
You can override hardware back button action as below inside **app.component.ts**. 
Remember to call `registerBackButtonAction` after `Platform.ready()`.

```
import { Platform, App } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'

})
export class MyApp {

  constructor(public platform: Platform, private app: App) {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {

          let nav = this.app.getActiveNav()

          if (nav.canGoBack()) {
            // If there are pages in navigation stack go one page back
            // You can change this according to your requirement
            nav.pop();

          } else {

            // If there are no pages in navigation stack you can show a message to app user
            console.log("You cannot go back");
            // Or else you can exit from the app
            this.platform.exitApp();
          }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: I was calling registerBackButtonAction() from each page rather than app.component.ts. Thanks for your assistance.